# Why does the "Recent Items" folder get so large when it only contains shortcuts

Tags: windows

In Windows 7, the Recent Items folder is located in C:\users\\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent Items.

The folder is called "Recent Items" when you use file explorer and is called "Recent" when you use the Command Line to find it.

It is part of the roaming profile and in our organisation, often brings people over their profile limit. When you look in the folder it contains a load of shortcuts but the size of the folder is much larger than the total of files is contains.

I am showing hidden files and system files.

Answer (score 3):

Even though a shortcut may be only a few characters, the minimum file size on disk is 4KB

Answer (score 1):

Check `\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\CustomDestinations` and `\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations` the easiest way to get to these is type `shell:recent` in the start button search box.

Files in these locations can get large. Delete them, they are just jump list shortcuts.